# I made a Custom UIView covered by UIButton. But I can't change the property at other class

Tags: swift

```
ㅣ [       ] ㅣ   
ㅣ [ image ] ㅣ
ㅣ [       ] ㅣ <- Cover the Button
ㅣ   Label   ㅣ
```

I want to make Custom Button look like above.
So I made a .xib and .swift file
and set like this.
[image]

And then I write the .swift

```
class ImageLabelVerticalButtonView: UIView {
    private let xibName = "ImageLabelVerticalButtonView"

@IBOutlet weak var imageView: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var btnTitle: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var btn: UIButton!

override init(frame: CGRect) {
    super.init(frame: frame)
    commonInit()
}

required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: coder)

}

func commonInit() {
    let view = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(xibName, owner: self, options: nil)!.first as! UIView
    view.frame = self.bounds
    view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    self.addSubview(view)

}

func setting(_ image: String, _ title: String) {
    self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)
    self.btnTitle.text = title
}
}
```

Next I want to use this CustomView at other class. so I declared this View like this.

```
var imgLabelBtn: UIView = {
    let view = ImageLabelVerticalButtonView(frame: CGRect(x: 5, y: 5, width: 60, height: 80))
    view.setting("star_x1", "HaHa")
    return view
}()
```

`Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` at the `setting()` func's `self.imageView.image = UIImage(named: image)` line

What am I wrong set the func?

Comment: Have tried debugging the issue? Place a breakpoint on that line and see what''s nil. My guess is that `UIImage(named:)` is returning nil for you

Comment: I try to change the setting() func to setting(_ title: String) and apply it . but title didn't change...